# awk command to select values from intervals defined by pairs of columns

Tags: awk

I am trying to design an awk command to select lines with a value column 2 that is  in the range of values defined by pairing specific columns of a line together. It has application in calling single nucleotide polymorphisms that are not within 50 nucleotides of exon boundries. The file looks like this:

```
ID  X   start   end start   end start   end start   end  
Fal1825_c6  802 2   62  62  239 239 362 362 934  
Fal1821_c2  152 1   19  22  159 159 263 264 398  
Fal18279_c7 41  1   177 177 598                 
Fal18376_c3 367 1   251 251 421                 
Fal18748_c2 601 1   152 152 489 489 499 499 677  
Fal18748_c2 500 1   152 152 489 489 499 499 677  
Fal18792_c3 750 1   234 234 459 459 762 762 83  
Fal19487_c2 89  1   177 177 270 270 409 411 459
```

I want to only print lines where the value of second column  falls in the range (”start” + 50) and (“end” - 50), for any "start" and "end" pairing on that line (pairings only made from "start" and "end" columns next to each other),  i.e. between ($3+50 and $4-50) or ($5+50 and $6-50) or ($7+50 and $8-50), and so on, considering all the pairs of start-end columns for the component.

The output would look like:

```
ID  X   start   end start   end start   end start   end  
Fal1825_c6  802 2   62  62  239 239 362 362 934  
Fal18376_c3 367 1   251 251 421             
Fal18748_c2 601 1   152 152 489 489 499 499 677  
Fal19487_c2 89  1   177 177 270 270 409 411 459
```

My attempted command looked like this

```
awk '{a=3; b=4; while ($a > 0) do {if ($2 > ($a + 50) && $2 < ($b + 50)){print $0} else {a+2, b+2} }'
```

Thank you

Comment: You never alter the values of `a` and `b`: `else {a+=2; b+=2}`, and I would write the loop as `while (a < NF)`. Note the difference between `a` and `$a` -- `a` is a variable (like in C), so when used by itself just refers to its value; `$a` first substitutes the value *then* returns the value of that field number (example: `a=2; print a, $a` would return `2 X` for the first line

Comment: Also, awk does not use the `do` keyword in a while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '{
for (i = 3; i <= NF; i += 2)
  if ($2 > $i+50 && $2 < $(i+1)-50) { print; next } 
}' FILE
```